# Getting a valid Google access token for Chrome Web Store APIs access from outside a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-oauth, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an issue over Google OAuth and Chrome Web Store APis.

Some **context** before starting with the tech stuff.

I have a popular Chrome Extension that delivers in-app purchases: purchasing an item the extension goes "pro", so usage limits are expanded.
Last year the audience asked me to make a porting on Firefox (thanks to the newly available *WebExtentions APIs*), and I started delivering both versions.
The Firefox version does not support in-app purchase at this moment, but people are starting to ask for it (let's think the FF version as an alpha version, so not all features are guarantee to be supported).

**Problem**: That said, I don't want to implement a secondary payment service using Google Pay APIs or other similar APIs and I'd like that if a user makes an in-app purchase on Chrome, it is delivered on FF as well.

***Hoped* Solution**: I thought it would have been easy to use the [Google Chrome Web Store APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/api_index). Making an user authorising its Google Account from the FF add-on I could understand if it was a paying user or not, thus enabling or disabling the "pro" limits.

Here are the steps I did.

***Step 1*** - Create a new app on the Google Cloud Console (I already have the one used on the Chrome Extension):
[image: Google Cloud Console Configuration]
And enable the Chrome Web Store APIs:
[image: Chrome Web Store APIs enablement]

***Step 2*** - Jump on Firefox JS console (inside the Options page of the add-on, so I have all the WebExtensions APIs enabled), and call the method to get a valid token (the code is quick and dirty, not enhanced and written just as a POC):

```js
var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly'];
var url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?'
+ 'client_id=xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
+ '&response_type=token'
+ '&scope='
    +encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' '))
+ '&redirect_uri='
    +encodeURIComponent(browser.identity.getRedirectURL());
browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {interactive: true, url: url})
  .then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Using the `browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()` function I got a valid token from the returning result (in the query string on the *access_token* parameter).

Now I get call the Chrome WebStore APIs with no issue (I thought) with this simple code:

```js
//access token
var token = 'previous_access_token';
//Google Chrome immutable Ext. ID from the store
var GOOGLE_CHROME_EXTENSION_ID = 'XXXXYYYYZZZ....'; 
//endpoint to get all purchased items (see https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/payments#resource)
var CWS_LICENSE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', CWS_LICENSE_API_URL+ GOOGLE_CHROME_EXTENSION_ID + '/payments');
req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    var license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    console.log(license);
  }
}
req.send();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work at all, getting the following error:
[image: Chrome WebStore API access error]
*(`You don't have access to licensing data for App ID: xxxxyyyzzzzz`)*

I have the following evidences:

1. If I use a token got from the Chrome Extension using `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` the call is ok
2. If I run the same script inside the Options page of the Chrome Extension, I get the same error
3. A specific Chrome WebStore API actually work (the [get items](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items#resource) API)

I guess for some reason Chrome WebStore APIs are not accessible using a token produced outside a specific context (i.e. Chrome extension subject of the call).

Does anyone have evidence of this? Google team are you there :) ?

Comment: While waiting for a competent answer you can check if there's a difference to the request performed in Chrome using Fiddler or a similar low-level inspection tool.

Comment: There seem to be no difference...it's probably related to Google app specific configuration for chrome extensions :(